# Is it possible to run Spring cloud on java 6?

Tags: java-8, spring-cloud, java-6

I need to run spring cloud on Java 1.6.

I tried spring Initializr which gave Java 1.8 in build.gradle even though selected one is Java 1.6.

I looked into [Which Java version is supported by Spring Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878637/which-java-version-is-supported-by-spring-cloud/30882370#30882370) which wasn't much help.

I tried compiling Spring cloud on java 6 which resulted in

" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener "

which is

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/BootstrapApplicationListener : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

If its possible, posting the config required in gradle script would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use Java 6 and Spring Cloud.

The baseline is Java 7. A couple of Spring Cloud projects have optional modules that require Java 8 and hence JDK 8 is required to compile the whole project, but the modules target Java 7 unless needed.

Next year, starting with the Edgware Release Train, Spring Cloud will move to a Java 8 baseline following Spring Framework 5 and Spring Boot 2.